# What is the word for the two numbers in a set with the largest range?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, $1$ and $4$ have the highest difference. Is there a word for that relationship, rather than just "highest difference" or "greatest range"?

Comment: The *range* of a set is the difference between the largest value and the smallest.

Comment: updated with "range", thank you @AJStas

Answer (score 0):

Diameter? http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter

The diameter of a subset of a metric space is the least upper bound of the set of all distances between pairs of points in the subset.

Comment: Would this be relevant outside of metric space?

Comment: Numbers are a metric space

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the 'extremes' of the set.